# C Program output confusion

Tags: c

Can someone explain why the output of this program is false??

x && y gives 1. Still the output is false.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    if(x && y == 1)
    {
        printf("true.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because of operator precedence rules, `x && y == 1` = `x && (y == 1)`

Comment: You probably meant something like `(x && y) == 1`.. but `x && y` is preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `==` has a higher precedence than `&&` So first this get's evaluated:

```
x && (y == 1)
```

```
y == 1  // 2 == 1
//Result: false
```

Which is false and then second:

```
x && false  //1 && false
//Result: false
```

So the if statement will be false

For more information about operator precedence see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x && y == 1)
```

Is the same as

```
if( ( x != 0 ) && ( y == 1 ) )
```

Here,`x != 0` is true, but `y == 1` is false. And since at least one of the operands of `&&` is false, the condition evaluates to false and the `else` part executes.

Comment: It doesn't really help if you don't say anything about operator precedence.

Comment: Yeah . You're right. I mis-interpreted the question a bit and did not see "`x && y` gives 1. Still the output is false.". Now @Rizier123 has a correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly stated X = 1 & Y = 2;
Now with your expression

```
X && Y == 1
```

The expression is evaluated as
Y == 1 (Precedence Rule, Also output is False)

X != 0 (Its True)

Now && is Logical And Operator, so it evaluates to True only if both the parts in expression evaluates to True!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to false, then 2 and 2 and it is different from one.
What you're asking is whether both x and y both are worth 1. If this happens say true but false